# How to exclude multiple nodes based on their ID in taxonomy term view?

Tags: views, 8

In taxonomy term view I want to exclude multiple nodes based on their id.

I tried to add a new CONTEXTUAL FILTER so I can handle multiple values in my Content: ID but the problem here is that it overwrites the url taxonomy/term/%/edit.

Also I have tried to add Content: ID filter in my FILTER CRITERIA but I cannot add multple values in "Not equal" field.

How can I solve that?

Comment: You'd have to continually add the filter. A Contextual Filter is not what you are looking for.

Comment: i think you should hook_view_alter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Add more than one ID Filter

You can simply solve it by adding as many **Content: ID** Filters as you need, each excluding only one node. As you already know set the `Operator` to **Is not equal to** and enter one value, then add another **Content: ID** Filter and so on for all the nodes you need to exlude.

### Use Regular expression

Or you can use the `Operator` **Regular expression** in a single **Content: ID** Filter. This way you can use a regex pattern that matches all the ID numbers you want to exclude.

For example the expression `(2[45])` matches two numbers, 24 and 25, so those two nodes would be filtered and shown in results.

In your case you need to *exclude* some numbers, so you would have to have a regex that excludes. That is a bit out of scope for this question so I won't go into it. There are online regex generators you can use to help you construct the expression, but I expect it would take some time, regex is notorious for being complex and mind-boggling.

For whole range of numbers take a look at this tool: [Regex Numeric Range Generator](http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/). Don't forget you need to modify the expression to exclude the list!