# How to override nid filter to accept multiple values on views

Tags: 8

I have read a dozen of open tickets on this issue, but none of them explains how to solve this.
Lets say I have a raw array of nids and wanting to override the query in a hook for the nid filter.
The nid filter allows only 1 value or some of the operators given in the image below.

[image]

There isnt an operator "is one of" as in the taxonomy reference filter. So how could this be overriden and allow multiple values for the nids?
Is this possible perhaps within the hook_views_query_alter()?

Comment: You can add more than one NID filter, and even change the operator between them to OR from AND if needed. You can also use the last option `Regular expression`? Here is an example: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/267914/how-to-exclude-multiple-nodes-based-on-their-id-in-taxonomy-term-view/267930#answer-267930

Comment: You could also use `Regular expression` with `^[nid1|nid2|nid3]$` replacing nid1 etc with the actual IDs.

Comment: @Jaypan The regex is a bit buggy, if there is a nid=8, and i put that in the regex, it will also take the nids 88 or 888 in the result.

Comment: Is making a views plugin a good solution?

Comment: Ahh, yeah, I gave it a range rather than a set. Try this: `^(nid1|nid2|nid3)$`

Comment: That works actually, thanks :)